# Websafe encoding of hashed string in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, base64

I am creating a re-director of sorts in nodejs. I have a few values like 
userid // superid

these I would like to hash to prevent users from retrieving the url and faking someone else's url and also base64 encode to minimize the length of the url created.

http://myurl.com/~hashedtoken
where un-hashed hashtoken could be something like this
55q322q23
55 = userid

I thought about using crypto library like so:

```
crypto.createHash('md5').update("55q322q23").digest("base64");
```

which returns: u/mxNJQaSs2HYJ5wirEZOQ==
The problem here is that I have the / which is not considered websafe so I would like to strip the un-safe letters from the base64 list of letters, somehow. Any ideas about this or perhaps a better solution to the problem at hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a so called *URL safe* variant of Base64. The most common variant, described in RFC 4648, uses `-` and `_` instead of `+` and `/` respectively, and omits padding characters (`=`).

Most implementations of Base64 support this URL safe variant too, though if yours doesn't, it's easy enough to do manually.

Comment: I end up using urlsafe-base6 npm library for what you describe. I encode to base64(unsafe) then use library to encode to safe.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used.  Comments welcome :-)

The important bit is buffer.toString('base64'), then URL-safeing that base64 string with a couple of replace()s.

```
function newId() {
  // Get random string with 20 bytes secure randomness
  var crypto = require('crypto');
  var id = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('base64');
  // Make URL safe
  return id.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, '');
}
```

Based on the implementation [here](https://github.com/RGBboy/urlsafe-base64/blob/master/lib/urlsafe-base64.js).

Makes a string safe for URL's and local email addresses (before the @).