# Encrypt CryptoJS without special characters

Tags: node.js, url, base64

using **nodejs**
 I am trying to generate an unique URL for user to **conform email address**. From that URL user will be able to **verify the email account** by decrypting the ciphertext and **comparing ciphertext  data with database** . I am using **CryptoJS** to generate the url.

`let url = 'http://localhost:4000/newUser/get/'+ciphertext ;`

Problem is that in ciphertext, it contains forward slash " / " eg:

`http://localhost:4000/newUser/get/U2FsdGVkX189ZNKKQrYgqU90DDwkl/W3hRTSGO1yvUMaDilPJmz9YYI3d1/E3i9C`

Router is **processing " / " on the URL**, thus router is searching for the directory **that is actually part of ciphertext**. If there is any solution for **not including " / " or special characters in ciphertext**, please help. **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: please provide node.js code you're using to generate ciphertext

Comment: `ciphertext.replace(/\//g,"-")`? (And then change `-` back to `/` on the server before comparing it to the database)

Comment: If this is a token, then you **must not** use some kind of ciphertext. Just generate a random token, store it in your database and encode it with URL-safe Base64 encoding. When the user clicks it, you decode the token and query the database to see if there is such a token.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Websafe encoding of hashed string in nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639645/websafe-encoding-of-hashed-string-in-nodejs)

Comment: Use URL encode will solve your problem, refer to this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992231/slashes-in-url-variables

Comment: thanks  @apsillers
`.replace()` works well.

while decrypt, I've used

`ciphertext = ciphertext.replace(/\+/g, 'aFaFa').replace(/\//g, 'bFbFb').replace(/=+$/, 'cFcFc');`

while encrypt, I've use 

`ciphertext = ciphertext.replace('aFaFa', '+' ).replace('bFbFb', '/').replace('cFcFc', '=');`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily replace the special characters with any of text like:

```
ciphertext.toString().replace('+','xMl3Jk').replace('/','Por21Ld').replace('=','Ml32');
```

Do not forget to replace these strings back with special characters

```
dataString.toString().replace('xMl3Jk', '+' ).replace('Por21Ld', '/').replace('Ml32', '=');
```

Hope this will help to solve your problem

Answer (score 5):

However, `.replace()` will only replace first occurrence.

To be more precise, you can use something like this :

```js
// Original Text
var ciphertext = 'asda+dasd+asdas/asdasd/sadasdasd/dadasd=adsasda=dasd=';

// Replaced Text
var dataString = ciphertext.replace(/\+/g,'p1L2u3S').replace(/\//g,'s1L2a3S4h').replace(/=/g,'e1Q2u3A4l');
console.log(dataString);

// Back to Original Text
ciphertext = dataString.replace(/p1L2u3S/g, '+' ).replace(/s1L2a3S4h/g, '/').replace(/e1Q2u3A4l/g, '=');
console.log(ciphertext);
```

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, for @JaiKumarRajput's answer,

He encoded the string with,

```
ciphertext.toString().replace('+','xMl3Jk').replace('/','Por21Ld').replace('=','Ml32');
```

Now, I have no idea how `xMl3Jk`, `Por21Ld`, `Ml32` works. So, i also don't know if it can mess my string somehow. 
Plus, As I have to perform this on decoding as well. So, Why wont I use something like this (What already exists),

```
encodeURIComponent(ciphertext.toString('base64'))
```

I know it still introduces `%` char. But as its getting used in **URL**. In which its a escape char.

How does it matter more than doing something that can mess my code up ??

> NOTE: I used it and had no issue, It doesn't mean I either had found any issue with the top one. That didn't feel neat. Its only my humble opinion, So if u don't like it? Ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

I have got the same problem, this works out for me:

```js
const aesKey = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('aeskeyaeskeyaeskeyaeskeyaeskey32');
const aesIv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('0123456789abcdef');
const aesOptions = {
  iv: aesIv,
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
};

const plaintext = 'iamtheoriginal';
const ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, aesKey, aesOptions).ciphertext.toString(); // 'c3a48990119bdfe40b6c32ec2aca8b93'

const encoded = {ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ciphertext)};
const decodedText = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encoded, aesKey, aesOptions)); // 'iamtheoriginal'
```

The ciphertext is 'c3a48990119bdfe40b6c32ec2aca8b93', has no special chars, and can be decrypted back to the original text, and it can encrypt all utf8 words like Chinese and even emoji.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for excluding / while crypto generate a encryped string.

I had face the same issue and then i found [urlencode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/urlencode)

```
const urlencode = require('urlencode');
 
let xx = {
    chatRoomId: 37,
    userId: 1,
    doctorId: 2
}

xx = JSON.stringify(xx)
//encode 
let x = (urlencode(xx, 'gbk')); // '%CB%D5%C7%A7'

// decode gbk
let y = urlencode.decode(x, 'gbk'); // original plain text
console.log(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Original Text 
let ciphertext = 'asda+dasd+asdas/asdasd/sadasdasd/dadasd=adsasda=dasd=';
let encodeText = encodeURIComponent(ciphertext);
console.log(encodeText)

let decodeText = decodeURIComponent(encodeText);
console.log(decodeText)
```

you can use like this.
first encode your ciphertext like above and concatenate that encodeText with ulr

```
let url = 'http://localhost:4000/newUser/get/'+encodeText ;
```

and then decode that encodeText from ulr