# Angular Router handling "/" in a router variable

Tags: angular, npm, hash, routes, cryptojs

I have been working on Angular project with routing , so lets consider a route like this below.

```js
  {
    path : 'preview/:Id',
    loadChildren : () => import('./path/preview/preview.module').then( m => m.PreviewModule),
  }
```

So this `route` could be having alphanumeric values like (a-zA-Z0-9) and also special character like `/` , hash value produced by [crypto.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) like below.

```
preview/QQZnNw+VjBg/cAXvy6nxdiQ==
```

so In this above route param `Id` will have some value like this `QQZnNw+VjBg/cAXvy6nxdiQ==` , that is what am trying to achieve.

> Error : **But unfortunately am getting error stating unrecognised route because , this above value has "/" in its route.**

Previously what i have tried is that i have tried adding regex like this `/:Id(/[\\S]+/g)` to the route param so that it could accept this route ,

```js
  {
    path : 'preview/:Id(/[\\S]+/g)',
    loadChildren : () => import('./path/preview/preview.module').then( m => m.PreviewModule),
  }
```

Please , can anyone help me find a way.

Comment: Why don't you produce hexadecimal hash strings with crypto.js instead of base64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61077372/7315145).

> I have created two utility functions to  replace **"/"** with some hashcode when encrypting and while decrypting that hashcode back to **"/"**.

```js
 convertSpecial = (text: string) => {
    const ciphertext = this.encrypt(text);
    return ciphertext.replace(/\+/g,'p1L2u3S').replace(/\//g,'s1L2a3S4h').replace(/=/g,'e1Q2u3A4l');
  }

  unconvertSpecial = (ciphertext: string) => {
    ciphertext = ciphertext.toString().replace(/p1L2u3S/g, '+' ).replace(/s1L2a3S4h/g, '/').replace(/e1Q2u3A4l/g, '=');
    const text = this.decrypt(ciphertext);
    return text;
  }
```

so while redirecting ,

```html
<a href="#" [routerLink]="['/preview', convertSpecial(item?._id)]" > </a>
```

on Mounting the component ,

```js
ngOnit()
{
this.Id = this.unconvertSpecial(this.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UrlMatcher`.

```ts
function slashMatcher(path: string, param: string): UrlMatcher {
  return (
    segments: UrlSegment[],
    group: UrlSegmentGroup,
    route: Route
  ): UrlMatchResult => {
    const { length } = segments;
    const firstSegment = segments[0];
    if (firstSegment.path === path && length >= 2) { // firstSegment.path == preview
      const paramSegments = segments.slice(1);
      const paramPaths = paramSegments.map(segment => segment.path); // ["QQZnNw+VjBg", "cAXvy6nxdiQ=="]
      const mergedParam = paramPaths.join("/"); // QQZnNw+VjBg/cAXvy6nxdiQ==
      const idSegment: UrlSegment = new UrlSegment(mergedParam, { [param]: mergedParam });
      return { consumed: segments, posParams: { [param]: idSegment } };
    }
    return null;
  };
}

const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    matcher: slashMatcher('preview', 'Id'), 
    loadChildren : () => import('./path/preview/preview.module').then( m => m.PreviewModule),
  },
];

// In component
const id$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(map(params => params.get('Id')));
```

Comment: Thanks @fridoo will let you know if that helps

Comment: please check out my answer @fridoo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62319284/7315145)