# Crypto-js and Express How can I prevent crypto-js from adding slashes into encrypted IDs to prevent server from reading it as a new sub route?

Tags: node.js, express, encryption, cryptojs

I am encrypting a user id using `crypto-js` to send it via url like the following for the user to validate it on click:

> http://localhost:3000/api/customer/activate/U2FsdGVkX1DXzzLuf9TgBf31Mc2V/QBVAN05PovlNM

This is the encrypted user id:

> U2FsdGVkX1DXzzLuf9TgBf31Mc2V/QBVAN05PovlNM

Using crypto-js `encrypt`:

```
crypto.AES.encrypt(term.toString(), config.CRYPTO_PASSPHRASE_RES).toString(crypto.enc.Utf8)
```

When I run the API, it return `route not found`, and when I remove `/` from the encrypted user id, it worked.

How can I prevent crypto-js from adding `/` into encrypted IDs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing base64 encoded strings in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url)

Comment: You could also replace special characters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43399093/encrypt-cryptojs-without-special-characters

Comment: better pass that id as a query string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to use `encodeURIComponent()` and then `decodeURIComponent()` like the following:

```
encodeURIComponent(crypto.AES.encrypt(term.toString(), config.CRYPTO_PASSPHRASE_RES).toString());
```

It will replace `/` into something else.