# Cipher a string using crypto-js with hex encoding to make it url friendly

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

I am using `crypto-js` by [brix](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js). I have this function below that handles the encryption of a plain text.

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'
import AES from 'crypto-js/aes'

const SECRET = 'I am batman'
const plainText = 'This is Sparta!'

export function enc(plainText){
    // returns something like this U2FsdGVkX184He5Rp991JYAiCSdTwfZs8T3kJUk3zAc=  
    // but with random `/` and I dont want that
    // I want it to be Hex but .toString(CryptoJs.enc.Hex) 
    // is not working, it just returns an '' empty string
    // it's a string, I checked using typeof
    return AES.encrypt(plainText, SECRET).toString();
}
```

How do I make the enc(string) to return a `Hex` value which is url friendly?

Comment: If you have trouble with `/` why don't you use the URL-safe Base64 encoding?

Comment: Hi @ArtjomB. Yes but, .toString(CryptoJs.enc.Base64) isnt working on `AES.encrypt()`

Comment: It's already Base64-encoded. You just need to replace some characters (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17641505/1816580)).

Comment: @ArtjomB. replacing characters will affect the data integrity.

Comment: Well, you would replace them back when you want to use the ciphertext to decrypt it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You would likely want to do:

```
export function dec(cipherText){
   var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherText, SECRET);
   var hex = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
   var plain = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
   return [hex, plain];
}
```

This takes the encrypted `base64` string and will return the decrypted plaintext and `hexadecimal`.

EDIT: In regards to your comment and edited question:

```
const SECRET = 'I am batman'

function enc(plainText){
    var b64 = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plainText, SECRET).toString();
    var e64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(b64);
    var eHex = e64.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
    return eHex;
}

function dec(cipherText){
   var reb64 = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(cipherText);
   var bytes = reb64.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
   var decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(bytes, SECRET);
   var plain = decrypt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
   return plain;
}
```

The end result takes the `base64` string, makes it `hexadecimal` and returns the decrypted string.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Im sorry I think I "mis-asked" my question. I updated it. That was careless of me. What I meant is I want `enc(string)` to return `Hex` so I could use it in url.

Comment: Wow, thanks man. It worked. I just found out that NodeJs has a native Crypto implemantation with `aes-256-ctr` as well. What's your thoughts on that?

Comment: You're welcome! I'd say the native crypto might be a good thing to look into as I'm not sure how secure CryptoJS is for something that would be highly sensitive. Some of the methods CryptoJS uses seem dated and I'm not sure I like the default way in which it salts the encrypted string...

Comment: Hi, I have a concern. It seems that this setup `enc(string)` produces a different hex every iteration even if I encrypt the same string, which is not good coz I am keeping the the hex output as a reference for my data. 

`string1 = 23h52kh5242h235232 = string1`
`string1 = 23h52kh52gjh235144 = string1`

Comment: @CENT1PEDE: Well, that's sort of the point of encrypting something. If you are needing the string to be static then you'll likely want to hash it in some way instead.

Comment: I was able to achieve what I want using nodejs' crypto. The process is pretty much the same with what you did except you can explicitly tell the algo what to encode to. 

`crypto.createCipher('aes-256-ctr', SECRET).update(plainText, 'utf8', 'hex')` and the output is the same. My guess is there's something going on when you encoded it to base64, just a guess tho.

Comment: @l'L'l Two questions: (1) What is `e64` in the `enc` function snippet you posted? (2) What is the return type of `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` and `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt` methods?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: `e64` takes the resulting base64 string and makes it hexadecimal. For `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` the type would be `Base64`, for `decrypt` the return type is `Hexadecimal`, but for `ASCII` you can use `toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)`.

Comment: @l'L'l `e64` is actually a `WordArray`. I did some research in the meanwhile after posting the comment. For anyone else reading this, here is a more detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58524245/303685

Comment: @l'L'l We see it in hexadecimal whenever we print out any binary data because hexadecimal is a printable *notation*. It is not a data type. It is simply a way of writing something. That doesn't mean that there's an underlying hexadecimal data type. You can write any numeric data in the hexadecimal notation. In contrast, a *data type* not only represents an underlying value but it also has a *size*.

Comment: Can anyone suggest me the corresponding decryption algorithm so that I can decrypt via another language for example in the server end?